# Unexpected Partial behavior

Tags: typescript

Need help to understand what is going on with types in this code:

```
interface UserDTO {
  id: string;
  email: string;
}

const input: Partial<UserDTO> = {};
const userDTO: Partial<UserDTO> = { id: "", ...input };

const email = userDTO.email;
```

I expect `email` variable to be of type `string | undefined` but got just `string` instead. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need to enable `strictNullChecks` options.

Take a look
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdoBEAqB5ZAbwChllgATALmXTClAHMBuU5CAWzmABsa6GIFsQC+xYggD2IOuRAAHAK5gaABThQwwODwA8GbPgB8yALxERrKTLDJFmKLjxqNWnfodOT5wuWrIAIgCAGmQAOgjQJVtLcWtZTm4eAEYzOWiwxN4raQSuXgAmNPtDPEz8nmYgA

All work fine.